No vertexes where edges connect
Never seen this one before. I tried to move selectes faces in edit mode as usual, and saw this:

it looked like some vertices moved and some stayed, so I went to the vertex mode and saw this:

Looks like there are almost no vertices to select? there are none at the most points where edges meet, though edges are selectable as usual. Is this some kind of bug? Or did I do something wrong?
I just moved from 4.1 to 4.2.

nothing weird here as well.
UPD: oh, I made a boolean union operation before this happened, and looks like it caused this somehow, because the mesh before union is ok. same question though: what happened and how to save my model

Try Mesh > Merge > By Distance. To remove doubled verts. That's what it looks like to me.

only those selectable vertices merged, when the merge distanse got big enough. On the other hand, the second mesh with the same problem magically healed after restarting blender
